# Terraform provision private VM on Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ip, provisioning, terraform

I'm new to Terraform. I have a subnet with two Ubuntu VMs. One is VM `A`, which has a public IP, and the other is VM `B`, with a private IP and no public IP. Is there a Terraform way of provisioning files and running commands on `B` without first having to SSH into VM `A` and then into VM `B`?

From what I've found, the `file` provisioners in Terraform require a `connection` block like so:

```
      # Example Azure VM provisioner block
      provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
          "rsync -Pav user@A:~/install.sh ~",
          "rsync -Pav user@A:~/file.txt ~",
          "sudo ~/install.sh"
        ]
        connection {
          type     = "ssh"
          user     = "${var.ssh_user_username}"
          host     = "<something to put here>"
          private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/azure_key_rsa")}"
          timeout  = "1m"
          agent = false
        }
      }
```

But since I can't connect to the private IP directly in Terraform, I'm not sure what to put for the `host` field to make this provisioner successful.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this in Terraform. There's [an ongoing issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/8367) about allowing ssh tunnels for the same purpose with some work-arounds

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your needs correctly, based on my understanding you want to ssh to your VM B then execute `install.sh`, am I right? According to my knowledge, you could do it with `terraform`. You could use `CustomScript` to execute your `install.sh`, the script is executed by Azure, you don't need ssh to the VM. Terraform also support `CustomScript`, you could refer to this [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_extension.html).

Comment: @Walter-MSFT You are right, I was wondering if there was a way to directly provision a VM within a private network with no public IP within Terraform. That looks like exactly what's needed, could you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, you could not do it with terraform directly. 
You could use [Custom Script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-features) to execute your `install.sh`, the script is executed by Azure, you don't need ssh to the VM.

The Custom Script Extension configuration specifies things like script location and the command to be run. This configuration can be stored in configuration files, specified on the command line, or in an Azure Resource Manager template. Sensitive data can be stored in a protected configuration, which is encrypted and only decrypted inside the virtual machine. According to your scenario, it seems that what you need.

Terraform also supports CustomScript, you could refer to this [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_extension.html).

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  location             = "West US"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.test.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions"
  type                 = "CustomScriptForLinux"
  type_handler_version = "1.2"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "hostname"
    }
SETTINGS
```